# MySQL does not roll back after delete transaction fails

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using such construction:

```
mysql_query('BEGIN') or die('BEGIN transaction failed!');
$query = "DELETE FROM transaction";

try {
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Db error', 1);
    }

    $query = "  INS ERT INTO transaction
                SELECT ....."; // just buggy request
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Db error', 1);
    }

    mysql_query('COMMIT') or die('COMMIT transaction failed!');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    mysql_query('ROLLBACK') or die('ROLLBACK transaction failed!');

}
```

but for some reason, the "delete" transaction does not roll back and the table stays empty.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: make sure db engine is `innoDB` or `BDB` and dont use mysql_* api is deprecated

Comment: u r right... its MyIsam ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MySQL Server (version 3.23-max and all versions 4.0 and above)
>   supports transactions with the InnoDB and BDB

Please change the table engine to `innoDB` in order to support Transactions

here is how you can go to change engine

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```